# Rails "magic" joins not working - activerecord not finding linked table entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two models in my app, CompanyUk, and CompanyName. CompanyUk hasmany CompanyNames. Activerecord is creating CompanyUk.CompanyNames, but it won't find any CompanyNames. Here's the code:

```
class CompanyName < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :CompanyUk, :foreign_key => "company_number"
end

class CompanyUk < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :CompanyNames, :dependent => :destroy, :foreign_key => "company_number"

  validates_presence_of :company_number, :reg_office, :type, :incorporation_date #, :next_accounts_date, :next_return_date # should eventually have these

  validates_uniqueness_of :company_number, :case_sensitive => false

  validates_associated :CompanyNames

  set_inheritance_column :kind
end

class CreateCompanyUks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :company_uks do |t|
      t.string :company_number, :null=>false
      t.text :reg_office, :null=>false
      t.string :type, :null=>false
      t.string :business_nature
      t.string :status
      t.date :incorporation_date, :null=>false
      t.date :last_accounts_date
      t.date :next_accounts_date
      t.date :last_return_date
      t.date :next_return_date

      t.primary_key :company_number

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end



class CreateCompanyNames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :company_names do |t|
      t.string :company_number, :null=>false
      t.string :name, :null=>false
      t.date :date_adopted, :null=>false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The contents of the database:

```
irb(main):011:0> CompanyUk.all
=> [#<CompanyUk id: 1, company_number: "12345", reg_office: "Example office", type: "Private company limited by shares", business_nature: nil, status: nil, incorporation_date: "2011-05-28", last_accounts_date: nil, next_accounts_date: nil, last_return_date: nil, next_return_date: nil, created_at: "2011-05-28 09:47:19", updated_at: "2011-05-28 09:47:19">]

irb(main):012:0> CompanyName.all
=> [#<CompanyName id: 1, company_number: "12345", name: "foo ltd", date_adopted: "2011-05-28", created_at: "2011-05-28 09:47:19", updated_at: "2011-05-28 09:47:19">, #<CompanyName id: 2, company_number: "12345", name: "foo ltd", date_adopted: "2011-05-28", created_at: "2011-05-28 10:09:29", updated_at: "2011-05-28 10:09:29">, #<CompanyName id: 3, company_num
ber: "1", name: "foobar ltd", date_adopted: "2011-05-28", created_at: "2011-05-28 0:10:52", updated_at: "2011-05-28 10:10:52">]
```

Despite there being multiple CompanyNames:

```
irb(main):009:0> CompanyUk.all.first.CompanyNames
=> []
```

In addition, creating a new CompanyName through CompanyUk.CompanyNames doesn't set the CompanyNumber (the primary key for CompanyUk, and the foreign key set on the relations) correctly.

So, is there any way to fix this? Or even better a good reference for how models and associations work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a particular reason for going against the convention?

E.g.: this:

```
has_many :CompanyNames, :dependent => :destroy, :foreign_key => "company_number"
```

... should be:

```
has_many :company_names, :dependent => :destroy
```

... as long as the migration is:

```
class CreateCompanyNames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :company_names do |t|
      t.belongs_to :company_uk, :null=>false
      t.string :name, :null=>false
      t.date :date_adopted, :null=>false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Guides for working with migrations and associations in Rails 3:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Note that Rails relies heavily on *convention over configuration* to make things Just Work (TM). Going against these conventions, unless really necessary, can often cause a headache :)

Comment: I've read both of those guides, and I haven't seen the naming conventions for this explained, which is one of my greatest frustrations - none of the conventions seem to be documented.

Comment: Switching the name of the association as suggested has Rails doing a join, but it's not joining in company_number. When I request CompanyUk.all.first.company_names the only record it selects is for a CompanyName with a different company_number from the CompanyUk. (However the association in the reverse direction works correctly on a CompanyName with a company_number that matches that of a CompanyUk).

Comment: @Marcin agreed, these conventions are not really documented, and are just assumed.

Comment: @Marcin did you update the foreign key in the `company_names` table? It should now be `company_uk_id`.

Comment: @Jits: OK, so there's no way to get rails to join on primary keys?

Comment: Ah, you have a non standard primary key for the `company_uks` table. You need to put `set_primary_key :company_number` in the `CompanyUk` model. This may help in getting Rails to join on the primary key.

Comment: I think you also need to put `:id => false` in your migration to prevent Rails from generating a default `id` column. So your migration will have something like: `create_table :company_uks, :id => false do |t| ...`